# Creating lstlistings for Java files in multiple Java folders

Tags: java, file

I did write it to have a solution [for my problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437220/how-to-import-java-source-code-from-multiple-folders-to-latex). But I don't know if my code is ok. Can you please check it?

**Problem:**

I want to include all my Java files from all my projects (created with Netbeans), the projects are stored in one folder, into a LaTeX document. I solved it with this code:

```
package dir;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Dir {

    private static String fileType;
    private static String fileName;
    private static String pathName;
    private static String folderName;
    private static String oldFolderName = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File(".");
        content(currentDir);
    }

    public static void content(File dir) {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    pathName = file.getName();
                    if (pathName.equals("src")) {
                        pathName = "main";
                    }
                    content(file);
                } else {
                    fileType = Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));

                    if (fileType.equals("text/x-java")) {
                        fileName = file.getName();
                        folderName = file.getParentFile().getName();

                        if(folderName.equals("src")){
                            folderName = file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getName();
                        }else{
                            folderName = file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getName();
                        }

                        if(!folderName.equals(oldFolderName)){
                            System.out.println("\\section{" + folderName + "}");
                        }

                        if(!pathName.equals("")){
                        System.out.println("\\subsection{" + pathName + "}");
                        }


                        System.out.println("\\subsubsection{" + fileName + "}");
                        System.out.println("\\lstinputlisting[language=java]{" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "}");
                        System.out.println("");
                        pathName = "";
                        oldFolderName = folderName;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am especially frustrated about following part:

```
if(folderName.equals("src")){
    folderName = file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getName();
}else{
    folderName = file.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getName();
}
```

Is there a better way to loop through all the `.getParentFile()` until you get the `.getParentFile().getName()` of the folder named "src"?

Furthermore one question: my code doesn't iterate sorted through my folders and files. I mean, if the subfolder of the folder I am in are like 3, 4, 5 and 6, the code just don't open folder 3 first, but just chooses a random file. It would be nice if you could help me to fix it.

Comment: You'll want to include the actual description of your problem in this question. This helps reviewerse see at one glance what you want to be doing instead of needing to follow a link

Answer (score 1):

to me it stroke odd that you use old `java.io` classes to list files, while using the newer (not-so-new-anymore) java 7 `java.nio` classes to determine file type.
I say you should use [`Files.isDirectory(Path p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) and [`Files.newDirectoryStream(Path p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path)) to check and list files in directory.

Furthermore, if you want to traverse a directory tree, you have the wonderful [`Files.walkFileTree()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) that does all the traversing for you.  You need to implement a `FileVisitor` that has interception points for start and end of directory and of course for visiting a file.  I believe this can help you in detecting src directories.